# Computing $\mathrm{Vect}_k(M)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

$\mathrm{Vect}_k(M)$ is the isomorphism classes of real $k$ rank vector bundles over $M$.
In Bott-Tu book they give only an example:
For contractible manifolds it is $\mathrm{Vect}_k(M)$ is a point.
I don't think I could understand well only by this example.
Could you give me other nontrivial examples?
In Exercise 6.10 of this book.
It is asked: Compute $\mathrm{Vect}_k(S^1)$.

Comment: What did you try? Can you think of any interesting vector bundles on $S^1$?

Comment: In this exercise it asked Vect$_k(S^1)$. For $k=0$, rank 0 vector bundle on $S^1$ is $S^1$ itself. Then Vect$_0(S^1)$ is the isomorphism class on $S^1$: $f: S^1\rightarrow S^1$. Such maps characterized by integer number. So I thought Vect$_0(S^1) = Z$. This exercise asks for such isomorphism classes for general integer $k$. Let me know if my idea is incorrect. :)

Comment: How about $k=1$?

Comment: Rank 1 bundle i.e., it’s a line bundle which looks like a cylinder or a Möbius band. I have no idea more than that...

Comment: Hint: Look up clutching functions

Comment: I looked up it. Is it a similar concept to transition functions to construct a fiber bundle?

Comment: By the way, $\textrm{Vect}_0(S^1) = 0$. All of those maps you described give the same bundle up to isomorphism.

Comment: Maps from a circle to another circle is described by exp(iθ) -> exp(imθ). It isn’t the winding numbers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number